# Scala and mongodb different model version

Tags: mongodb, scala, oop, playframework

I was thinking about an interesting scenario and trying to figure out the best and elegant solution to avoid a future problem, I'm more than sure that here someone has a great idea to fix this.

This.is the scenario:

In a scala play framework (actually this is valid for any oo language) I have a simple class user representing my actual user model:

```
Case class user(name:String, age:Int){}
```

Now I have my JSON implicit converter and I'm able to save many users in a MongoDB database (or any database).

After some time I decide to add a new property to my user class, let's say:

```
Case class user(name:String, age:Int, surname:String){}
```

Now my app is updated and if I run it everything will work fine until I try to load an old user saved with the old model.

In that case, I have, of course, an exception, cause the data from the database are not valid (actually the surname property is missing) and no object can be created.

My question is, what's the best way to deal with this especially using scala and a non-relational database as MongoDB?

Thanks all.

**UPDATE**

the suggestion of using Option[String] is the best solution

Answer (score 1):

You can add the new field as Option[String].
So it will be None if it is missing (for old data). and it will be Some(value) (for new data)